# In an acceptance test, how do I know when my asynchronous events are?

Tags: events, node.js, cucumber, acceptance-testing

So here's the rub - I have a system that, when an event occurs, fires off a chain of disparate asynchronous code (some code even fires off more events).

Now during acceptance testing I fire that same event - but what strategy should use to notify the test runner that all the subsequent events are finished and ready to move on to the next step?

I started out just waiting for fixed amount of time - but I that was always just a fudge.
And now, I'm hooking in to the tail events and moving on when they have all finished. But I can see this becoming v. complex as the system grows.

Just wondering if there is an alternative strategy that I've missed. Any suggestions?

FWIW I'm using [cucumber.js](http://cucumber.no.de/) & [zombie](https://github.com/assaf/zombie) to test an [express](http://expressjs.com) app on [node.js](http://nodejs.org/).

Cheers and thanks for your time,

Gordon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously, the solution will be different depending on the application, but I find it helpful to architecture my applications in such a way that callbacks for the top-level asynchronous functions are tracked all the way to the end. Once all the top-level callbacks are done, you can fire some event or call some callback that indicates everything is over. Using something like [async's `parallel`](https://github.com/caolan/async#parallel), you could potentially do something like this:

```
eventEmitter.on('someEvent', function(some, data, callback) {
  async.parallel([
    function(cb) { firstAsyncThing(some, cb); },
    function(cb) { secondAsyncThing(data, cb); }
  ], function(err, results) {
    // called when all functions passed in the array have their `cb` called
    callback(err, results);
  });
});
```

So then you can pass a callback into your event:

```
eventEmitter.emit('someEvent', 'some', 'data', function(error, results) {
  // the event has been fully handled
});
```

Comment: parallel looks very useful - I'll give it a whirl. And I'll start passing a callback thru the chain of events and see how that works out. Thanks!